# How do you deal with insert/update/delete scenarios inASP.net webapplications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I've an UI (angular JS) where user would want to be able to `add,update or delete`  multiple schedules for a given SoftwareImage (see the API model below) and from the backend(ASP.net web api) I want to be able to handle these cases,following is the algorithm we have between UI and backend but it seems a very hacked way,I want to get opinion from experts on how do you handle such scenarios?

```
namespace Dashboard.Model.ApiModels
{
    public class PostcommitSchedule
    {
        public string SoftwareImage { get; set; }
        public List<PostcommitdayTime> PostcommitdayTime { get; set; }

    }

    public class PostcommitdayTime
    {
        public string day { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }

}
```

SELECT query:

```
SELECT si.software_image,pbs.day_of_week_id,pbs.time_of_day FROM postcommitbuild_schedule pbs
join software_images si on si.software_image_id=pbs.software_image_id
where si.software_image='LNX.LA.3.6'
```

ALGORITHM

```
 If empty object
      Delete all records
 Else
   Run a select query(see above)  to see if there are any existing records for the given SoftwareImage(SI)

    If records exits
     Delete the existing records 
     Insert the new records
   Else
     Insert the new records
```

Comment: Do you wanna create a CRUD app?

Comment: @JesusCarrasco - I want to design an API model and logic to create an ASP.net web API that can handle insert,edit and delete scenarios

Comment: Great!, i was malunderstanding, thinking on the tag (angularjs) that you need some help on how create de services to consum the API, sorry.!

Comment: @user3508811 you should also use Entity Framework with LINQ instead of SQL.